# XAMARIN IOS project release Rebuild taking hours?

Tags: performance, xamarin, xamarin.ios

XAMARIN IOS project release Rebuild taking hours and After waiting for 12 hours I cancelled and rebuild it again and tried multiple time.
Not even a single timeI was able to complete the build it successfully.
In the build output window log following?
Rebuild All started: Project: BMPOS.iOS, Configuration: Release iPhone...

Any idea what went wrong

Build output after enabled MS Build. 
I cancelled it manually that why it say Build FAILED at the end

```
Rebuild All started: Project: BMPOS.iOS, Configuration: Release iPhone ------

    2>Build started 12/10/2017 12:00:55 PM.
    2>Building with tools version "14.0".
    2>Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0". This toolset may be unknown or missing, in which case you may be able to resolve this by installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or the build may have been forced to a particular ToolsVersion for policy reasons. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="14.0". For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=293424.
    2>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (entry point):
    2>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
    2>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
    2>Task "Message"
    2>  Configuration=Release
    2>Done executing task "Message".
    2>Task "Message"
    2>  Platform=iPhone
    2>Done executing task "Message".
    2>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\iPhone\Release\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('bin\iPhone\Release\')).
    2>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\')).
    2>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\iPhone\Release\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\iPhone\Release\')).
    2>Done building target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "BeforeRebuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Rebuild" depends on it):
    2>Done building target "BeforeRebuild" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "BeforeClean" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Done building target "BeforeClean" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "UnmanagedUnregistration" skipped, due to false condition; ((('$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)' != '$(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)' or '$(RegisterForComInterop)' != 'true' or '$(OutputType)' != 'library') or
    2>                    ('$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)' == '')) and
    2>                   Exists('@(_UnmanagedRegistrationCache)')) was evaluated as ((('' != '' or '' != 'true' or 'Exe' != 'library') or
    2>                    ('' == '')) and
    2>                   Exists('obj\BMPOS.iOS.csproj.UnmanagedRegistration.cache')).
    2>Target "CoreClean" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Using "Delete" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.dll".
    2>Task "Delete"
    2>  File "obj\iPhone\Release\\TempCA\BMPOS.iOS.pdb" doesn't exist. Skipping.
    2>  File "obj\iPhone\Release\\TempCA\BMPOS.iOS.exe" doesn't exist. Skipping.
    2>Done executing task "Delete".
    2>Task "ReadLinesFromFile"
    2>Done executing task "ReadLinesFromFile".
    2>Task "FindUnderPath"
    2>  Comparison path is "bin\iPhone\Release\".
    2>Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
    2>Task "FindUnderPath"
    2>  Comparison path is "obj\iPhone\Release\".
    2>Done executing task "FindUnderPath".
    2>Task "Delete"

    2>Task "RemoveDuplicates"
    2>Done executing task "RemoveDuplicates".
    2>Using "MakeDir" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.dll".
    2>Task "MakeDir"
    2>Done executing task "MakeDir".
    2>Task "WriteLinesToFile"
    2>Done executing task "WriteLinesToFile".
    2>Done building target "CoreClean" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_CleanMdbFiles" skipped, due to false condition; (Exists('$(TargetPath).mdb')) was evaluated as (Exists('D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\bin\iPhone\Release\BMPOS.iOS.exe.mdb')).
    2>Target "_SeparateAppExtensionReferences" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "AssignProjectConfiguration" depends on it):
    2>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(Identity)' != '' And '%(ProjectReference.IsAppExtension)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('..\BMPOS\BMPOS.csproj' != '' And '' == 'true').
    2>Done building target "_SeparateAppExtensionReferences" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_SeparateWatchAppReferences" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "AssignProjectConfiguration" depends on it):
    2>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(Identity)' != '' And '%(ProjectReference.IsWatchApp)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('..\BMPOS\BMPOS.csproj' != '' And '' == 'true').
    2>Done building target "_SeparateWatchAppReferences" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "BclBuildAddProjectReferenceProperties" in file "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "AssignProjectConfiguration" depends on it):
    2>Done building target "BclBuildAddProjectReferenceProperties" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "AssignProjectConfiguration" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "CleanReferencedProjects" depends on it):
    2>Task "AssignProjectConfiguration"
    2>  Project reference "..\BMPOS\BMPOS.csproj" has been assigned the "Release|AnyCPU" configuration.
    2>Done executing task "AssignProjectConfiguration".
    2>Done building target "AssignProjectConfiguration" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "CleanReferencedProjects" depends on it):
    2>Using "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    2>Task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput"
    2>  Resolving project reference "..\BMPOS\BMPOS.csproj".
    2>  Project reference "..\BMPOS\BMPOS.csproj" has not been resolved.
    2>Done executing task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput".
    2>Done building target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "CleanReferencedProjects" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' and '$(BuildProjectReferences)' == 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('true' != 'true' and 'true' == 'true' and '..\BMPOS\BMPOS.csproj' != '').
    2>Done building target "CleanReferencedProjects" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "CleanPublishFolder" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Task "RemoveDir" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PublishDir)'=='$(OutputPath)app.publish\' and Exists('$(PublishDir)')) was evaluated as ('bin\iPhone\Release\app.publish\'=='bin\iPhone\Release\app.publish\' and Exists('bin\iPhone\Release\app.publish\')).
    2>Done building target "CleanPublishFolder" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "AfterClean" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Done building target "AfterClean" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_ComputeTargetArchitectures" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Task "ParseDeviceSpecificBuildInformation" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(DeviceSpecificBuild)' == 'true' And '$(TargetiOSDevice)' != '' And '$(_CanDeployToDeviceOrSimulator)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' == 'true' And '' != '' And 'True' == 'true').
    2>Done building target "_ComputeTargetArchitectures" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_ComputeTargetArchitectures" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    2>Target "_CleanUploaded" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Task "Delete"
    2>  File "bin\iPhone\Release\.uploaded" doesn't exist. Skipping.
    2>Done executing task "Delete".
    2>Done building target "_CleanUploaded" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_ComputeTargetArchitectures" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    2>Target "_GenerateBundleName" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "_CleanAppBundle" depends on it):
    2>Done building target "_GenerateBundleName" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_GenerateBuildSessionId" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "_SayHello" depends on it):
    2>Using "GenerateBuildSessionId" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Messaging.Tasks.dll".
    2>Task "GenerateBuildSessionId"
    2>  Generated session id: 319b1c4ad11c8246e68e142c5cf1ceef
    2>  Generated build app name: BMPOS.iOS
    2>Done executing task "GenerateBuildSessionId".
    2>Done building target "_GenerateBuildSessionId" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_SayHello" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "_CleanAppBundle" depends on it):
    2>Using "SayHello" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Messaging.Tasks.dll".
    2>Task "SayHello"
    2>  Connecting to Mac server 192.168.0.20...
    2>  Starting connection to 192.168.0.20...
    2>  Executing SSH command 'whereis xcodebuild'...
    2>  Executing SSH command '/usr/bin/xcodebuild -license check'...
    2>  Sending Message Xamarin.Messaging.MessageStatusMessage to topic xma/message-status
    2>  Sending Request Xamarin.Messaging.GetActiveClientsMessage to topic xma/clients
    2>  Sending Message Xamarin.Messaging.MessageStatusMessage to topic xma/message-status
    2>  Received Response of Xamarin.Messaging.GetActiveClientsMessage to topic build7384Atlan/response/xma/clients
    2>  Registering message handler 'Xamarin.Messaging.Client.DefaultHandler`1[[Xamarin.Messaging.AgentStatusMessage, Xamarin.Messaging.Common, Version=1.1.6.34, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756]]'
    2>  Registering message handler 'Xamarin.Messaging.Client.DefaultHandler`1[[Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.CancelBuildMessage, Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts, Version=4.7.10.22, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756]]'
    2>  Registering message handler 'Xamarin.Messaging.Client.DefaultHandler`1[[Xamarin.Messaging.ClientStatusMessage, Xamarin.Messaging.Common, Version=1.1.6.34, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756]]'
    2>  Registering message handler 'Xamarin.Messaging.Client.DefaultHandler`1[[Xamarin.Messaging.MessageStatusMessage, Xamarin.Messaging.Common, Version=1.1.6.34, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756]]'
    2>Done executing task "SayHello".
    2>Done building target "_SayHello" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_SetMtouchProjectDirectory" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "_CleanAppBundle" depends on it):
    2>Done building target "_SetMtouchProjectDirectory" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_CleanAppBundle" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Using "RemoveDir" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.dll".
    2>Task "RemoveDir"
    2>  Removing directory "bin\iPhone\Release\BMPOS.iOS.app\".
    2>Done executing task "RemoveDir".
    2>Task "Delete"
    2>  File "bin\iPhone\Release\mtouch.stamp" doesn't exist. Skipping.
    2>Done executing task "Delete".
    2>Done building target "_CleanAppBundle" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj".
    2>Target "_GenerateBundleName" skipped. Previously built successfully.
    2>Target "_CleanDebugSymbols" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets" from project "D:\Deven\BMPOS XAMARIN\BMPOS R2 XAMARIN\BMPOS\BMPOS\BMPOS.iOS\BMPOS.iOS.csproj" (target "Clean" depends on it):
    2>Using "GetDirectories" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.dll".
    2>Task "GetDirectories"
    2>  GetDirectories: 2017-12-10T12:01:01.1642240-05:00 - Started
    2>  GetDirectories: 2017-12-10T12:01:01.1662241-05:00 - Initializing
    2>  GetDirectories: 2017-12-10T12:01:01.1702628-05:00 - Initialized
    2>  GetDirectories: 2017-12-10T12:01:01.1772241-05:00 - Serializing intputs
    2>  GetDirectories: 2017-12-10T12:01:01.1982258-05:00 - Executing
    2>  Sending Message Xamarin.Messaging.MessageStatusMessage to topic xma/message-status
    2>  Sending Request Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Contracts.ExecuteTaskMessage to topic xvs/Build/4.7.10.22/execute-task/BMPOS.iOS/319b1c4%2FGetDirectories
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(410,3): warning : The client build7384Atlan has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/4.7.10.22/execute-task/BMPOS.iOS/319b1c4%2FGetDirectories
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(410,3): warning : The client build7384Atlan has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/4.7.10.22/execute-task/BMPOS.iOS/319b1c4%2FGetDirectories
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(410,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\5156\fe36becf\source\xamarinvs\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 171
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(410,3): error : AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(410,3): error : ClientDisconnectedException: The client build7384Atlan has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/4.7.10.22/execute-task/BMPOS.iOS/319b1c4%2FGetDirectories
    2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(410,3): error : 
    2>  GetDirectories: 2017-12-11T01:49:43.3854234-05:00 - Finished
    2>Done executing task "GetDirectories" -- FAILED.
    2>Done building target "_CleanDebugSymbols" in project "BMPOS.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.
    2>
    2>Build FAILED.
    2>
    2>Time Elapsed 13:48:47.76
    Build

 has been canceled.
```

Comment: Enable diagnostic MSBuild output and review where the process is hanging.

Comment: Hi Sushi , I already enabled theMS Build

Comment: If so, where in the diagnostic logging does it stop/hang?

Comment: I have added diagnostic, Can you please have a look into it?

Comment: You are getting disconnected: `ClientDisconnectedException`. Try building your project directly on macOS via Visual Studio for Mac (or MSBuild)